# Sending Array as Param in Retrofit Get Request A

Tags: android, arrays, retrofit

I am trying to send an array as parameter in GET request in Retrofit
Eg: prod = [1,2,3,4]

- Tried almost every solution present on Stack OverFlow, GitHub
- Non of them worked

Can someone explain how to make an array and send get request in RetroFit

Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
@GET(".....")
Call<ResponseBody> getSomthingApi(@Query("prod") ArrayList<String> values);
```